# Jest test suite fails to run on Circleci

Tags: node.js, jestjs, circleci

I have set my Circleci container in Ubuntu 14.04, and my node version is 6.11.2. I have written a basic test case using Jest.It works perfectly in my local environment, the test suit runs and the test case passes. However, when I am trying to deploy it using Circleci, the build fails as the test suite fails to execute. Here's the error circleci is throwing-

FAIL  **test**/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at _load_jsdom (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:17:41)
```

I can't figure out where the error actually is since it executes perfectly in my local environment. I have used the same node version in my circleci build as well.

Comment: Which version of your Jest are you using ? Please show package.json of your project.

Comment: Same is happening with me on Shippable.

Comment: Are you sure that you set the NODE_ENV variable to test?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the docker image has *exactly* the same node version as your local environment. E.g.

```
docker:
  - image: circleci/node:8.9.4
```

Comment: I actually did that. Still this problem persists.